# difference between these two way of writing function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function-call

I would like to know what is difference in writing in below 2 ways :

Approach 1:

```
var onCallback = function(result) { 
    alert('way1');
};

function1(onCallback);
```

Approach 2:

```
function2(function(result) {
    alert('way2');
});
```

Comment: Readability, usability, maintainability, re-usability of the function. 

Else it does the same thing.

Comment: approach #1 in principal allows for accessing `onCallback` from another container embedding the js (like html `frame`, `iframe`elements or `svg`roots).

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1 could be reused. (which might do some problems, because the code can be altered, but shouldn't)

Approach 2 has no refference

that's the only difference

Comment: `onCallback` is also anonymous; it's just that it's also referenced by a variable.

Comment: in approach 1, some other code portion might alter the definition of 'onCallback'. feels like a maintenance disaster to happen.